# Why is the output of wien bridge oscillator sinusoidal?

Tags: function-generator

I have been studying Wein Bridge Oscillator for a function generating project. I am curious how output of the oscillator is always sinusoidal. A rigorous mathematical reasoning would be great.

Comment: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/wien_bridge.html

Comment: Thanks JonRB, I have gone through the article you mentioned. The article, like similar others, explain "how" the sinusoidal waves are generated, but not why the output is sinusoidal but not something else.

Comment: Think about how the sine function is derived from a triangle and then rotate a corner of that triangle around in a circle.

Comment: Oh, I see. Now that makes a perfect sense to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the output of a Wien bridge oscillator is *not* always sinusoidal. If the gain at the critical frequency is less than 3 the oscillator will not oscillate. If the gain is more than 3, the amplitude will increase until clipping sets in. Any real Wien oscillator needs an AGC (automatic gain control) loop to stabilize its output.

Bill Hewlett developed a simple stabilization loop as part of his master's thesis. He used the thermal response of a lamp filament as a cheap and reliable sensing element, and went into business making very good audio sine wave generators in a garage rented by Dave Packard. The combination of names may ring a bell. The garage is still in existence.

Answer (score 1):

If an oscillator circuit is well designed, it fulfills Barkhausens oscillation condition: Loop gain of unity at one single frequency only.

That means: There is only one single frequency for which the amplitude as well as the phase condition is fulfilled - and only for this single frequency self-sustained oscillations are possible. For all other frequencies either the phase condition or the amplitude condition (or both) are not fulfilled.

**Example** (Wien oscillator): The passive part of the circuit (bandpass) has a transfer factor of 1/3 for a frequency which produces a phase shift of 0 deg. Hence, we need an amplifier for closing the loop with a gain of "3".